# Convert Agora AudioFrame to Unity AudioClip

Tags: unity-game-engine, agora.io

I want to get the raw data of the audio from Agora, and streaming it to a Unity [AudioSource](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/AudioSource.html).

Using the `AudioRawDataManager.onPlaybackAudioFrameBeforeMixing` callback, I can get the raw data in the AudioFrame form, but I cannot figure out an easy way to convert the AudioFrame to Unity [AudioClip](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/AudioClip.html) class.

Does anyone have experience?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

You will just need to assign raw data bytes from AudioFrame into the audioclip object you have.
see AudioClip's SetData().

Rough steps:

1. Create a limited queue
2. The callback buffer is sent to the limited queue
3. Assign the filled buffers from the queue to generate AudioClip.
4. AudioSource plays the AudioClip

The length of this queue is the length of the buffered audio selected by the user.